# Date and and time Range with certain conditions

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a database containing traffic volume on the road.
I have to fetch the data from datagridview with certain conditions.

I tried:

```
while ((fromDate = fromDate.AddDays(interval)) < EndDate )
```

but it generate output like

```
7/1/2014 7:10  <br />
7/5/2014 7:20  <br />
7/2/2014 7:10  <br />
7/5/2014 7:20 <br />
```

But I want my output should be like:

```
1st iteration  7/1/2014 7:10 -- 7/2/2014 7:20 <br />
2nd iteration  7/2/2014 7:10 -- 7/3/2014 7:20 <br />
3rd iteration  7/3/2014 7:10 -- 7/4/2014 7:20 <br />
4th iteration  7/4/2014 7:10 -- 7/5/2014 7:20 <br />
5th iteration  7/5/2014 7:10 -- 7/6/2014 7:20 <br />
```

Comment: Please explain a little specifically what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried already.

Comment: More specifics, please...  Is the range you want to loop over `7/1/2014 7:10 -- 7/2/2014 7:20`, `7/2/2014 7:10 -- 7/3/2014 7:20`, etc?  At what granularity?

Comment: Yes. The input should be starting date (7/1/2014 7:10) and End date (7/30/2014 7:20 ) but the while loop go through all the dates and ranges between stating and End date with above condition.it's forecasting tool that's why i need previous values for future values

Comment: Looks like you need to add one day and 10 minutes each time?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you:

```
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2014, 5, 1, 7, 10, 0);
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2014, 5, 30, 7, 20, 0);

        while (d1.CompareTo(d2) < 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d1 + " -- " + d1.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(10));
            d1 = d1.AddDays(1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does not handle all the cases you might need for a forecasting tool. Still, I hope it will give you some ideas how to continue on your own.

```
    var fromDateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 7, 7, 10, 0);
    var endDate = fromDateTime.AddDays(10);
    while (fromDateTime < endDate)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", fromDateTime.ToString(), fromDateTime.AddDays(1).ToString());
        fromDateTime = fromDateTime.AddDays(1);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```